# Metadata migration

Tags: deployment, custom-metadata

I migrated the custom metadata type from lower to higher environment but I am unable to view any records. Is it anywhere related to profile access issue.

Comment: How did you migrate it ? What's your profile? You can try to query it via the SF Inspector on the higher env. If you're an admin and have access to setup you shouldn't have access issues.

Comment: Custom Metadata records are not migrated automatically with their parent types. You need to migrate the records as well.